# Finding the right spring constant (real world problem)

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, spring, estimation

My mother is disabled and uses a [trike elecromobile](https://www.travelscoot.com/assets/img/travelscoot_shopper.png) to get around but the seat is not spring-loaded.

The manufacturer is offering a spring loaded one but that is too expensive. I figure I could simply put a hairspring around the pipe that is the base of the seat, but I find myself unable to calculate what spring I need (I had newtonian physics and calculus in school but was yeeeeeeaaars ago).

The diameter of the pipe is 3 cm, the available height ~ 8cm and the weight of the person approx. 50kg. What must be the spring constant so the spring will carry the 50kg, yet budge a small amount when the device rolls over rougher terrain like cobblestone?

I apologize if this is not the right forum for the question, in that case please let me know about the appropriate one.

Comment: You might consider migrating to engineering stackexchange site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will start by answering the physics part of your question.

If you have a total range of motion of 8 cm, you will want to "budge a small amount" (like maybe 2 cm) when the person (weight 500 N) sits on the seat.

The equation is $F=k\cdot d$ where $F$ is the force, $k$ the spring constant and $d$ the displacement. That would mean you need a spring constant of $k = \frac{F}{d} = 25,000 N/m$. If your spring constant was less than 6000 N/m, the seat would sink more than 8 cm (and thus hit the end stop); if it's much stiffer than 20,000 N/m, it will not give a lot of travel to smooth out the bumps.

Note - modifying a mobility device is something not to undertake lightly. After all, your mother relies on its safe operation. If you are not sure what you are doing, there is a risk you make it less safe. That's something you won't want to do. Perhaps there are other solutions - the seat post of an office chair looks like it might work. Or an air-filled cushion could be a good option. But really - if you have already invested in this scooter, is the cost to upgrade the seat suspension a cost you are not willing to make?

The other thing to consider: larger wheels are an excellent way to smooth a ride over a bumpy surface. The wheels in the picture you linked are particularly small - that's really where the problem comes from. Choosing bigger wheels (not sure how that would work ... how is the propulsion force transmitted to the wheels?) would be my first choice for a modification if I felt so inclined.

Comment: Yes, the wheels look far too small for cobblestones. Perhaps that is why it is called a "shopper" - ie designed for getting around in a shopping mall. The website says it has to be lifted over kerbs ... If used only for mall-shopping, there may not be any need for additional suspension : the padding in the seat should be enough.